# Differentiability of a multivariable function at (0,0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Given a function $$
f(x, y) = \cases{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{x - y}& for $x ≠ y$ \\ 1& for $x= y$}
$$ 
I found the limit of the function when $x$ approaches $y$, i am getting infinity. Is it correct? And if yes, then obviously the function is not continuous at $x = y$ and hence not differentiable at $(0,0)$. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

For $x \ne 0$ we have $f(x,-x) =x \to 0 \ne 1 =f(0,0)$ as $x \to 0$.

Hence $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$, therefore $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.